# How to send direct messages using OAuth?

Tags: php, oauth, message, twitter-oauth

I am trying to make a twitter application. I have gotten my application to a point where users log in through Twitter's user verification system. I am also able to send status updates using my application. I have this function to send status updates:

```
function sendTweet($tx){

    $consumer_key = 'MY CONSUMER KEY';
    $consumer_secret = 'MY CONSUMER SECRET';

    $Twitter = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
    $Twitter->setToken($_SESSION['OT'],$_SESSION['OTS']);

    $text=$tx;
    $status=$Twitter->post_statusesUpdate(array('status' => $text));
    $status->response;

}
```

This `sendTweet($tx)` function works like a charm but now what i need to do is get a list of followers of a user and then send Direct Messages to them. How can I do this using oauth and PHP?

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendDirectMessage($user,$message)
{       $consumer_key = 'YOUR CONSUMER KEY';
        $consumer_secret = 'YOUR SECRET';

        $Twitter = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
        $Twitter->setToken($_SESSION['OT'],$_SESSION['OTS']);

        $myArray = array('user' => $user, 'text' => $message);

        $resp = $Twitter->post_direct_messagesNew( $myArray);
        $resp->response;
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe what you trying to do with this function it will help people to get along with you easily?